# c# EPP Auto Row Height

Tags: c#, excel

Like auto column height is there a function for auto row height?
The functionality is available in excel by double clicking on the row divider just  like a column but I can't find the function in code.

At the moment I am having to calculate the height but there must be an easier way?

Answer (score 2):

Use `ExcelRow.CustomHeight = false`:

```
sheet.Row(1).CustomHeight = false;
```

This will auto-size the height of the row even if you changed it before. Tested with:

```
DataTable dataSource = new DataTable();
dataSource.Columns.Add("Id");   
dataSource.Columns.Add("Title");
dataSource.Rows.Add("1", "Title1");
using (var excel = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage())
{
    var sheet = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Test");
    sheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dataSource, true);
    sheet.Row(1).Height = 5;
    sheet.Row(2).Height = 5;
    sheet.Row(1).CustomHeight = false; // This will auto-size the header
    excel.SaveAs(new FileInfo("Path"));
}
```

Comment: Neither your example nor the method in general seem to work (anymore?). EPPlus 4.1, LibreOffice Calc, Excel Online.

Comment: @Yegor: sorry to hear, currently can't test it